# Looping through all subfolders of path

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I read many answers on how to loop through subfolders of a directory but i saw that all of them are for looping only one level or 2 levels down. Is it possible to loop through all subdirectories of a folder? Consider a directory, say dir1. In dir1 there is dir2 and dir3. In dir2 there is dir4 in and in dir3 there is dir5. In dir4 there is dir6 and dir7 and in dir5 there is dir8 and dir9 and so on, lets consider "infinite subfolders". Is there any way to loop through all those levels of the dir1?

Comment: Talk with code.

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: If you do not want to write an script you can use "find". Like this: find . -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 1    . You can define your maxdepth

Comment: @Patrick85 I saw find somewhere but what if we dont know maxdebth?

Comment: @will1am You also can run "find ."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a recursive function

```
function run_path {
    # by default current dir
    local current=${1:-.}
    local subdir
    # removing trailing / if any
    current=${current%/}
    # do something
    echo "$current"
    for subdir in "$current"/*/; do
        # filtering non-existing file for example '*' not expanded
        [[ ! -e $subdir ]] && continue;
        # recursive call
        run_path "$subdir"
    done
}

run_path "<<path_to_run>>"
```

Another version to include "hidden" folders (which begins with .)
in this case . and .. must be excluded
Also symbolic links are not handled and may be excluded to avoid loops.

```
function run_path {
    # by default current dir
    local current=${1:-.}
    local subdir
    # removing trailing / if any
    current=${current%/}
    # do something
    echo "$current"
    for subdir in "$current"/*/ "$current"/.*/; do
        # filtering non-existing file for example '*' not expanded
        [[ ! -e $subdir || $subdir = */../ || $subdir = */./ ]] && continue;        
        # recursive call
        run_path "$subdir"
    done
}
```